# Меня перенаправляет на главную страницу XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

Вбиваю в URL адрес сайта на локалке и меня перенаправляет на главную страницу `XAMPP`. В настройках апача не особо еще разбираюсь. В чем проблема?

Вот содержимое файла `Htaccess`.

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev.guestcrew.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.guestcrew.com/$1 [L,R=301]


    # Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
    RewriteBase /

    # General Pages:
    RewriteRule ^contact-us.html$ contact.php [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^landing/(guest-blogger|blog-owners|advertiser|all-about).html$ landings.php?type=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^landing/advertiser-pro.html$ advertiser-pro.php [L,QSA,NC]

    RewriteRule ^google([^./]+).html$ google$1.html [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^./]+).html$ pages.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

    RewriteRule ^campaign/([0-9]+)-([^./]+) view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

    RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)-([^./]+)/$ filter.php?category=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^campaign-embed/([0-9]+)-([^./]+)/$ view.php?id=$1&title=$2&embed=true [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вы делаете, чего ожидаете, и что получаете в результате.

Comment: Хочу попасть в файл index.php и не могу,меня кидает на дашборд Xampp.Я создал виртуальный хост для данного сайта,если же обращаюсь через локалхост то все нормально,если создаю вирт. хост то вот появляется данная проблема!

Comment: пожалуйста, изложите в вопросе, какой адрес вы вводите в адресной строке браузера, чего именно ожидаете в результате (включая адресную строку), и что именно получаете (включая адресную строку).

Comment: Вбиваю адрес - guest/
Получаю - https://guest/dashboard/ а должен попасть в index.php

Comment: как вы видите сами, в приведённом вами файле нет упоминания слова *dashboard*. значит, такое перенаправление производится, скорее всего, либо в настройках *http*-сервера, либо в коде, выполняемом скриптами сайта.